# VueJS Render function - How do I add a reference to another component?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component which does not have a template. I am using the render function to build the vnodes of the component. I have a spinner component in my app which I want to add to this component. Does anyone know of documentation on the process of adding a component and referencing it for the CreateElement method? I am working on an example to show here. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In case you have specific problem with code, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , don't just describe your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use component name or component object for `CreateElement`:

```js
var comp = {
  render(h) { return h('div', ['Child Component ' + (this.value || '?')]) },
  props: ['value']
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h('div',[
                 h('comp', {props:{value:'1'}}),
                 h(comp)
               ]),
  components: {
    comp
  }
}).$mount('div')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments